# How can I programmatically get the Bluetooth MAC address of an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mac-address

I'm trying to do some proximity detection of iPhones but I need to get their **Bluetooth** MAC address programmatically. Does anyone knows how ?

I assume Bluetooth is activated but no device is paired with the iPhone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no public API to get this information.

If this is an internal or jailbreak application you can get the value of the `kLockdownBluetoothAddressKey` key via [liblockdown.dylib](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php?title=Liblockdown.dylib)

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping I could get it more or less the same way we can retrieve the WiFi MAC address...

Comment: I think that might be workable if the iPhone is in tethering mode over Bluetooth.

Comment: Please post code snippet for using kLockdownBluetoothAddressKey key via liblockdown.dylib

Answer (score 6):

On all devices I could get my hands on, the following rule seems to apply
 - iPhone wifi MAC address is one larger than iPhone bluetooth MAC address
 - iPad wifi MAC address is one less than iPad bluetooth MAC address.

It would be helpful if people check this on their iPhone or iPad, such that we can increase the confidence in the theory. I've checked on a few iPhone4, iPhone3 and iPad1 devices.

You can check it by opening Settings - General - About
and looking at "Wi-Fi Address" and "Bluetooth"

If the theory is correct, the following **legal** code will retrieve your bluetooth mac address:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <net/if_dl.h>
#include <string.h>

#if ! defined(IFT_ETHER)
#define IFT_ETHER 0x6/* Ethernet CSMACD */
#endif

void doMacTest() {
    BOOL                        success;
    struct ifaddrs *            addrs;
    const struct ifaddrs *      cursor;
    const struct sockaddr_dl *  dlAddr;
    const uint8_t *             base;

    // We look for interface "en0" on iPhone

    success = getifaddrs(&addrs) == 0;
    if (success) {
        cursor = addrs;
        while (cursor != NULL) {
            if ( (cursor->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_LINK)
                  && (((const struct sockaddr_dl *) cursor->ifa_addr)->sdl_type == IFT_ETHER)
                  && (strcmp(cursor->ifa_name, "en0") == 0)) {
                dlAddr = (const struct sockaddr_dl *) cursor->ifa_addr;
                base = (const uint8_t *) &dlAddr->sdl_data[dlAddr->sdl_nlen];

                if (dlAddr->sdl_alen == 6) {
                    fprintf(stderr, ">>>             WIFI MAC ADDRESS: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n", base[0], base[1], base[2], base[3], base[4], base[5]);
                    fprintf(stderr, ">>> IPHONE BLUETOOTH MAC ADDRESS: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n", base[0], base[1], base[2], base[3], base[4], base[5]-1);
                    fprintf(stderr, ">>>   IPAD BLUETOOTH MAC ADDRESS: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n", base[0], base[1], base[2], base[3], base[4], base[5]+1);
                } else {
                    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR - len is not 6");
                }
            }
            cursor = cursor->ifa_next;
        }
        freeifaddrs(addrs);
    }

}
```

Comment: Theory correct on my iPhone 4, but not on the iPod 4--there the last 5 hex digits are different.

Comment: In iOS 7 and later, if you ask for the MAC address of an iOS device, the system returns the value 02:00:00:00:00:00  https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=8222013a

Answer (score 0):

MAC Address for my iPhone4 iOS 5.0.1 was in the following order comparing their last digits:

```
63 = Bluetooth
64 = WiFi

iPad2 v5.0.1 was:

0D = Bluetooth
0E = WiFi
```

The iPod-Touch 2nd Generation iOS 4.2.1 was totally different set.

```
??.FC = WiFi
xx.04 = Bluetooth
```