# Determining unique Bluetooth MAC address for iPhone and Android

Tags: iphone, android, bluetooth, symbian, smartphone

Is it possible to determine the unique bluetooth MAC address for an iPhone and an Android (and to a lesser extent, other smartphones) from within an app on said device?  Is my assumption that the MAC address is universally unique correct?

A general yes or no would be helpful.  Example code in the case of an iPhone or an Android would be extremely helpful.

Comment: See my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969472/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-bluetooth-mac-address-of-an-iphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the bluetooth MAC address will always be unique.
In Android you can use the getAddress() api on the BluetoothAdaptor. 
It returns the MAC address as a String.

On iPhone it looks like there is no public API to read the MAC address , see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969472/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-bluetooth-mac-address-of-an-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

**Android**

Read up on the Bluetooth section of dev guide, specifically [Connecting Devices](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html#ConnectingDevices).

> About UUID
>
> A Universally Unique Identifier (UUID)
>   is a standardized 128-bit format for a
>   string ID used to uniquely identify
>   information. The point of a UUID is
>   that it's big enough that you can
>   select any random and it won't clash.
>   In this case, it's used to uniquely
>   identify your application's Bluetooth
>   service. To get a UUID to use with
>   your application, you can use one of
>   the many random UUID generators on the
>   web, then initialize a UUID with
>   fromString(String).

Comment: It is my understanding that there is a universally unique identifier associated with all bluetooth devices from the moment they leave the factory door.  For instance, also from you link "If a device is discoverable, it will respond to the discovery request by sharing some information, such as the device name, class, and its *unique MAC address*."  I am explicitly interested in the MAC address and it had better be universally unique.  If my assumption is wrong, then that would be a good thing to know too.