# How to get MAC Address of beacon when ranging and monitoring in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-location, ibeacon

I'm working on the app is able to detect UUID, Major ID and Minor ID. But now i want to get MAC Address of beacon when the app is detected the UUID of beacon. I dont know if is doable? I also googled but i cannot find out the way to get MAC Address of beacon. As far as i know, the beacon is based on the BLE, so i think if i use the BLE to scan the beacon, i can get MAC Address but i'm using Core Location to detect UUID, Major and Minor ID. Please give me some advice to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can not get the mac address of beacon.

Even you scan with bluetooth API,you can not get mac address too.

Also,refer to this link
[How can I programmatically get the Bluetooth MAC address of an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969472/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-bluetooth-mac-address-of-an-iphone)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I see in EstimoteSDK, it has a macAdress attribute. So it is able to get macAddress right?

Comment: They send MAC address in the scan response packet.Not get from API

Comment: This is correct.  You can read the mac on Android but not iOS or OSX.