# Get Bluetooth MAC Address on iPhone

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, swift, bluetooth

**Preamble**
I'm working on Xcode 7.0.1 with Swift 2

Are hours (update, days) that I try to understand how I can retrieve this information.
I have seen that there is a framework, [CoreBluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html), that maybe could help me. (update, definitely not!!)

Any idea? Objective-c/swift/c/c++.. whatever.. is the same.

I already test code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969472/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-bluetooth-mac-address-of-an-iphone#answer-7566761) but prints:

> >>>             WIFI MAC ADDRESS: 02:00:00:00:00:00
>     >>>
>   IPHONE BLUETOOTH MAC ADDRESS: 02:00:00:00:00:ffffffff
>    >>>   IPAD
>   BLUETOOTH MAC ADDRESS: 02:00:00:00:00:01

About this, I have read on official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW34):

> In iOS 7 and later, if you ask for the MAC address of an iOS device,
>   the system returns the value 02:00:00:00:00:00. If you need to
>   identify the device, use the identifierForVendor property of UIDevice
>   instead. (Apps that need an identifier for their own advertising
>   purposes should consider using the advertisingIdentifier property of
>   ASIdentifierManager instead.)

The question is: if other devices can read my bluetooth mac address, why I'm not able to?
I think that there should be a way to do it, for sure.

I also try snippets on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779715/how-to-get-mac-address-of-your-machine-using-a-c-program) (and other answers) but I never get real mac address.

I know that to know bluetooth information of mac I can run on terminal:

```
system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType | sed -n "/Apple Bluetooth Software Version\:/,/Manufacturer\:/p"
```

And to retrieve mac address only I can 'pipe' to previous command:

```
egrep -o '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}-){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'
```

I'm asking.. can I run this command on iPhone programmatically?

Actually, I have already tried, with this pseudocode:

```
script = ""
system("system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType > blueInfo.txt")
sleep
read from file "blueInfo.txt" its content
```

This code compile and "works", but fail on reading file that does not exist.

I'm currently thinking about dropping ):

Comment: Apple does not allow developers to identify a device by unique hardware identifiers. It has done so after many misuse of the identifier which could affect the user privacy.

Comment: You can't for privacy reasons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get MAC address of bluetooth low energy peripheral](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973098/get-mac-address-of-bluetooth-low-energy-peripheral)

Comment: @Magisch if you had read what I ask, you would not definitely marked it as duplicate: I asked for my MAC, not peripheral MAC.

Comment: @Velthune : Good research

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters [and the devs on this GitHub issue](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central/issues/77) have noted, it is impossible to retrieve the MAC address of the current device you're running it on, even though it would be possible to read it off from a second device, due to privacy concerns.